# Is there a solution for code completion of Factory Design pattern in vim

Tags: magento, vim, vim-plugin

So I have switched over to VIM for all of my coding. I use to use PHPStorm for my Magento development. One of the things that make development hard in Magento, and using an IDE, is the fact they use a Factory Design pattern for using classes.

For example to load the following class

Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

you would call with

Mage::getModel('catal/product');

I am looking for a way to be able to say

```
Mage::getModel('catal/product')->
```

And code completion give me a list of methods from Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

For the last two years people have been pushing for the following in PHPStorm and a solution has been developed for that IDE [Generic support for factory design pattern in PHP chaining (e.g. Magento, Doctrine, Kohana, etc..)](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6027)

PHPStorm has came up with a solution, where it allows you to create a mapping of classes that PHPStorm will use to give you code completion.

I am wondering with VIM is there a way I could use a similar mapping as to https://gist.github.com/colinmollenhour/937195, with a current Code Completion plugin or maybe some tips to creating my own plugin to offer this type of code completion. I have been looking at a few articles, it seems like it should be possible, but I have never coded anything for VIM.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit hard to follow. If you have a list of e.g. class names and you want to offer completion, you can implement a custom *insert mode completion*. See `:help E840` for a simple example; you can read the list of completions from an external command via `system()`.

To insert an amount of skeleton code with dynamic placeholders, *snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork][https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate]. A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion).

Comment: I have snipMate, that helps for just general code blocks, but not in terms of code completion of possible methods from a class.

Comment: I have no PHP background, and there's a lot of question text to digest. In any way, then a custom completion is the way to go. You have to write some Vimscript, but there are existing implementations. Grep `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/*.vim` for `omnifunc`.

Comment: Thanks, I removed some more of the text since I explained it a little more now. I will look into that stuff you just posted.